# Grouping values to a list in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

While reading a csv file using csv.DictReader

I get

```
[{'id': 1, 'status1': '1', 'status2': '2', 'status3': '3' }]
```

How can I manuplate while reading or later to get:

```
[{'id': 1, 'status': ['1', '2', '3']}]
```

TLDR;
I want to group similar fields into a list.

and/or - how can i do this in pandas pd.read_csv() too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define 'similar'.

Comment: like 'status1', 'status2', etc.. into 'status'

Comment: What kind of similarity is it? Will those 'similar' keys always be like `status1` or can be `statusA` or something or are there more variables like `other1`, `other2`?

Comment: there are other variables like other1 and other2 as well. currently Thierry's answer has given the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is certain that the only fields you want to group are those who end with digits, you can use a regex to identify them, and append their corresponding values to a list:

```
import re

def compact_dict(d):
    compact = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        # a group containing anything, followed by at least one digit
        m = re.match(r'(.*)\d+', key)  
        if m:
            # the key that we use is the original one without the final digits
            compact.setdefault(m.group(1), []).append(value)
        else:
            # not part of a group of similar keys, we just store the key:value pair
            compact[key] = value
    return compact

data = [{'id': 1, 'status1': '1', 'status2': '2', 'status3': '3' }]
out = [compact_dict(d) for d in data]
print(out)
# [{'id': 1, 'status': ['1', '2', '3']}]
```